# VBA: Login using Windows Authentication

Tags: vba, authentication, ms-access, ldap

I have a an Access App that requires the user to enter their Windows domain user and password to enter. I have used the following VBA code to accomplish this:

```
Function WindowsLogin(ByVal strUserName As String, ByVal strpassword As String, ByVal strDomain As String) As Boolean
    'Authenticates user and password entered with Active Directory. 

    On Error GoTo IncorrectPassword

    Dim oADsObject, oADsNamespace As Object
    Dim strADsPath As String

    strADsPath = "WinNT://" & strDomain
    Set oADsObject = GetObject(strADsPath)
    Set oADsNamespace = GetObject("WinNT:")
    Set oADsObject = oADsNamespace.OpenDSObject(strADsPath, strDomain & "\" & strUserName, strpassword, 0)

    WindowsLogin = True    'ACCESS GRANTED

ExitSub:
    Exit Function

IncorrectPassword:
    WindowsLogin = False   'ACCESS DENIED
    Resume ExitSub
End Function
```

I notice that sometimes when the information is entered correctly, access is denied. I tried to debug once and it gave the error: "The network path was not found.
" on the `Set oADsObject = oADsNamespace.OpenDSObject)` line.

Not sure why this occurs sometimes. Is it better to convert to LDAP instead? I have tried but can't construct the LDAP URL correctly.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but playing around with your code it looks like I get a TRUE on your function as long as a pass a valid strUserName and strDomain even if the password is ""

Comment: It's like a hit or miss. Strange behavior.

Comment: I ended up using `option compare binary` instead of `option compare database` reasoning is that `option compare database` doesn't give you good control of the CASES

Answer (score 5):

If the user is already authenticated via their Windows login, why make them enter the details again?

If you need to know which user is logged in, you can get the username very easily by the following function:

```
Declare Function IGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal sBuffer As String, lSize As Long) As Long

Function GetUserName() As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim sBuffer As String
    Dim lSize As Long
    Dim x As Long

    sBuffer = Space$(32)
    lSize = Len(sBuffer)
    x = IGetUserName(sBuffer, lSize)
    GetUserName = left$(sBuffer, lSize - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: You can also get the username with one line of code: `Environ("USERNAME")`

Comment: run `set username=` then see what `ENVIRON("USERNAME")` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In GxP environment it is additionally needed to enter at least password. It doesn't matter if You are logged to Windows, You need to confirm it again.