# How to log into AD while off the domain in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, active-directory

So I have been trying to add a level of security to a tool, and I came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144282/vba-login-using-windows-authentication). The code works when on the network/domain, but I need to use this somehow for people who are remote and not on the network, nor vpn'ed into the network. Is this possible? I am learning as I go here, so this may not even be feasible in the first place. Just looking for every avenue possible.

Example Code:

```vb
Function WindowsLogin(ByVal strUserName As String, ByVal strpassword As String, ByVal strDomain As String) As Boolean
    'Authenticates user and password entered with Active Directory. 

    On Error GoTo IncorrectPassword

    Dim oADsObject, oADsNamespace As Object
    Dim strADsPath As String

    strADsPath = "WinNT://" & strDomain
    Set oADsObject = GetObject(strADsPath)
    Set oADsNamespace = GetObject("WinNT:")
    Set oADsObject = oADsNamespace.OpenDSObject(strADsPath, strDomain & "\" & strUserName, strpassword, 0)

    WindowsLogin = True    'ACCESS GRANTED

ExitSub:
    Exit Function

IncorrectPassword:
    WindowsLogin = False   'ACCESS DENIED
    Resume ExitSub
End Function
```

**EDIT:** So @user2140261 told me about trying the `LogonUser` function from Advapi32.dll which looks like below:

```vb
Private Declare Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "LogonUserA" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonType As UInteger, ByVal dwLogonProvider As UInteger, ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean

Sub LoginTest()

    Dim logname As String
    Dim logpass As String
    Dim domainstring As String

    logname = "username"
    logpass = "password"
    domainstring = "domain.com"

    Call WindowsLogin(logname, logpass, domainstring)

End Sub
```

For some reason, this crashes Excel all together. Any reason why?

Comment: You could use the function LogonUser from the WinApi library "Advapi32"

Comment: When I try using that, it causes Excel to crash.

Comment: Then ask a question with the code you used for the API and i'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the sub `WindowsLogin` is dong in your orininal code but try the below:

```
Private Declare Function LogonUser Lib "Advapi32" Alias "LogonUserA" _
(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
ByVal dwLogonType As Long, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Long, phToken As Long) As Long

Public Sub LogUserOn()
 Dim strUserName As String
 Dim strPassword As String
 Dim strDomain As String
 Dim bResult As Boolean

 strUserName = "UserName"
 strPassword = "Password"
 strDomain = "Domain"

 bResult = LogonUser(strUserName, strDomain, strPassword, 2, 0, 0)

 If bResult Then
    MsgBox "Successfully Logged User In"
 Else: MsgBox "And Error Occured While Trying To Log User In " & vbCrLf _
            & "Error Code:" & Err.LastDllError
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't crash. Now to test it on a machine that isn't on the network.

Comment: Not working on a machine not on the domain. I guess I'll need to research more, and find another way to do this...

Comment: @JHStarner By "Not working" what do you mean, I have extensivly tested this method in many environments, and have never had it "not work". are you not even getting an Error Code, are you gettign any unhandled errors?

Comment: Getting an error code 1326. I looked that up, and it says it is for wrong username or password. I know both are correct, and the domain is correct as well. Will this not work if for some reason the Domain Admins have something to block this kind of login?

Comment: How are you entering the domain if it is not on the domain? The computer doesn't need to be connected to any netowrk at all, this method useing local information. If you test the exact same code on the same machine with the same cred's but on the domain do you get the same error?

Comment: It is successful on a machine in the domain. There in lies my original question, that have been misunderstood. Three cases. 1: Internal Employee, computer on domain (Should get all access). 2: Internal Employee, computer on other network, not vpn'd into domain, not touching domain (still needs all access). 3: External user (limited access to workbook). I need something that will allow an internal employees to enter their credentials and allow access if they are not on a company network or computer. AD and e-mail login seemed my only routes. [Flow Chart](http://i.imgur.com/AOUmTCn.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

As the answer in the post you referenced said, if you just need to know who is using the app, and apply security based on that, then you can just get the logged-in user's name from the OS.  The user can log into their laptop when disconnected using their cached credentials, and your app will be able to lock down whatever is needed based on the identity asserted by the OS.

**Update**

There are a couple of ways to get the User's identity from the OS.  One is the environment variables `%USERDOMAIN%` and `%USERNAME%`.  Another is the [WScript.Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6wt333f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object:

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WScript.Echo "Domain = " & WshNetwork.UserDomain
WScript.Echo "User Name = " & WshNetwork.UserName
```

You can validate that the user is logged into the correct domain, and then provide access to the secured features.

Comment: The problem is this is 500+ users. I don't have the list of people who will be using this. If I knew all users this was going to, then yeah, I would have an authorized list sheet somewhere, and just check against that. (Could be more, as company is 30,000+ people in total).

Comment: But what's your criteria for allowing access?  If it's just that the user is a domain user then you can check that from the cached credentials reported by Windows.

Comment: There are three potential users for this tool. Internal employee on the domain (should have access to all data). Internal employee not on the domain (should have access to all data). External client not on the domain (should have limited access). So I have internal on domain, and external taken care of. I am trying to find an answer to the second possibility.

Comment: JHStarner - How would you normally authenticate the employees not on the domain?

Comment: There isn't a normally, this is a new area that I have been given the task of doing.

Comment: So are you saying that these are users who would normally log onto the domain when in the office, but are now needing access to this tool remotely from a non-domain-joined machine?

Comment: Apologies, after discussing with boss, this is not the case. Even though an internal employee should have full access to the whole workbook, it is not expected for them to have the workbook on a non-company machine. Thus they will always open the workbook on a company workstation, or a company laptop. The laptops are domain joined in one way shape or form because our workstation logins work on any company machine.

Comment: Then my original answer stands.  Don't ask the user for his credentials and then try to verify them against a domain controller.  Instead, just rely on the user identity provided by the OS (Windows).

Comment: Then I'm still confused. What is too keep someone using it on a non-domain machine? What am I checking with that username check that does anything with the domain? (And remember, I still do not have a list of "authorized" users.)

Comment: When a domain user is working remotely with his company laptop, he still logs in with his domain username and password, and Windows authenticates him using credentials cached on the machine.  Windows knows that it is a domain user, and can tell you which domain he's logged on to.  That should be sufficient to authorize access based on the user being a member of your company domain.